# How can I update supportedLngs after i18n has been initialized

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next

I have general config for i18

```
i18n
  .use(ChainedBackend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .createInstance(
    {
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      lng: window.localStorage.getItem('i18nextLng') || 'en',
      debug: true,
      supportedLngs: ['en'], // fallback value, changed after configuration load
      initImmediate: false,
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
      },
      backend: {
        backends: [HttpBackend],
        backendOptions: [{ loadPath: '/configs/languages/{{lng}}.json' }],
      },
    },
    (error): void => {
      if (error !== undefined) {
        console.warn(error)
      }
    },
  )

export default i18n
```

after a request to api to get some configurations I can have new values for supportedLngs

In case I will use `i18n.init()`

```
 i18n.init({ supportedLngs: newSupportedLnsValues}, (error): void => {
         if (error !== undefined) {
           console.warn(error)
         }
       })
```

I get a warning in console that init should be used only one time

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 i18next: init: i18next is already initialized. You should call init just once!
```

In case I will use `i18n.createInstance()`

```
  i18n.createInstance({ supportedLngs: newSupportedLnsValues}, (err, t) => {
        if (err) return console.warn('something went wrong loading', err)
       // t('key'); // -> same as i18next.t
      })
```

this will not change default exported `i18n`

also tried cloneInstance

```
 i18n.cloneInstance({ supportedLngs: newSupportedLnsValues}, (err) => {
        if (err) return console.warn('something went wrong loading', err)
      })
```

but this also will not change default exported i18n

Any ideas how to update supportedLngs in already initialized i18n

Comment: Why not doing the i18next.init after you have all your needed information?

Comment: Alternatively, you need to createInstance from the beginning… and having 2 i18next instances… and never use the global instance